# How to know about new versions for the plugins in project build.gradle.kts?

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

For the implementations mentionened in my **app** build.gradle.kts, Android Studio shows a hint about new versions.
But what about the **project** build.gradle.kts and the plugin versions mentioned there? How do I know if there are new versions available?

That's what I currently have and I am wondering if I can increase the versions there and where to find those releases.

```
// project build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.45" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally Gradle downloads the plugins from public repositories like Maven Central or Google Android.

[Here is the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html).

And it is declared in build.gradle file like

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

[Here is the link for maven repository.](https://mvnrepository.com/)

And as far as I know Gradle highlights the plugins if there is a new version. By clicking the Elephant symbol on top right of the build.gradle (it appears if there is a new version), gradle downloads the newest version.

And if you want to check the plugins on maven, just search for it.

Like: [com.android.application.gradle.plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin)

Then click the newest version of the plugin. You will see a list. Maven, Gradle, Gradle(short), Gradle (Kotlin) etc. You can copy the code to your build.gradle.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Dependency Management**

You could setup a Dependency Check plug-in available for gradle that lists all known vulnerabilities of outdated dependencies of your project via a custom gradle task.

https://github.com/dependency-check/dependency-check-gradle

By adding to your `build.gradle.kts`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:9.0.9'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'
```

Then run
`gradle dependencyCheckAnalyze --info`
and look at the report under build/reports

**Java Package Repository**

To look for new releases you can check out mavencentral, using your jetbrains plug-in as an example
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin